# I'm trying to control heat remotely in a shop/garage that is subject to sub-freezing temps (which is OK with me when it is not in use)

Tags: hvac, thermostat, winter, workshop

I've learned that smart thermostats go into LO mode when temps drop below 35 and refuse to call for heat when in that mode. I've replaced the smart thermostat with a cheap mechanical thermostat that will call for heat when power is turned on to the gas unit heater it is connected to (which I can do remotely). At times I would like to be able to heat the shop to just above freezing - say to 40 for an extended period, but then be able to remotely raise the temp to 70 an hour before I plan to use the shop. I've tried connecting a second smart thermostat to do the increase in temp in parallel with the dumb(?) thermostat but it refuses to operate (screen goes blank every few seconds). I've connected the two tsats within 6 inches of each other. Would it make any difference if I made a separate run back to the heater for each? Seems like it would still be the same circuit...

Comment: parallel is parallel. with dumb thermostats, that's an OR logic (either can call for heat). you could just use a garage door or "universal" smart switch to manually call for heat by connecting the wires. you could put a dumb one in series with that relay, set for a max temp like 72, so that it doesn't just run like crazy, or run at all when commanded off.

Comment: You might want to park outside when heating; otherwise you have to pay/wait to heat 1000s of lbs of freezing cold metal you don't need to otherwise.

Comment: Which smart thermostats are you talking about that won't call for heat when their local temperature drops below 35degF?

Comment: ThreePhaseEel-Honeywell for sure - that's what I have. I've tried two different models. I've also been told by an hvac buddy that it's pretty common

Answer (score 2):

A smart 'stat won't care if a dumb 'stat is in parallel with it.

However, I am guessing you did not run a C wire to the smart 'stat.  So how is the smart 'stat powering itself?  In that case, the smart 'stat takes advantage of being wired in series with the solenoid valve at the furnace.  When it doesn't want heat, it allows a small amount of current to leak through. When it wants heat, it allows a large amount of current to leak through. The smart 'stat puts itself in series with that current, dropping some voltage and harvesting the power to charge its battery.  This mostly works because the smart 'stat has its battery to carry it through times when it can't harvest enough.

However once you put a dumb 'stat in parallel with it, this shorts out the R and W wires.  Now the smart 'stat has NO voltage or current at all, and that trick does not work. It must coast on its battery. Which would work at a low duty cycle where the dumb 'stat is calling for heat infrequently.

The problem is, when you're out there working on it, well, what have you done with the heat? :) I bet you have turned the heat on with the dumb 'stat.  So the R and W wires are shorted and the smart 'stat sees no power at all.  It can't configure and can't charge battery.  It would sort itself out eventually, but not while you're standing there watching it lol.

For what it's worth.

Comment: Ahhhhh, the C wire!! I did _not_ connect it to the smart 'stat. Your explanation makes total sense. I'll be doing some wiring tomorrow after it warms up - it's -10F tonight. I'll let you know...

Answer (score 1):

Example Nest thermostat (I have one)

It is smart but only if you give it power to operate. The R and the C have to be connected.

It knows when I am not home (using my cell phone as signal) and switches to ECO mode. ECO mode is the standby mode and you can preset the lowest and the highest temp, usually lower than your normal 70F. In this case you can set the ECO mode to 40 and it will keep it there. You can also turn on the ECO mode any time you want.

It knows when I am back home and switches to normal setting.

I can remotely (from Cell phone) start heating/cooling way before I am home if I choose so.

I am sure other smart models do similar but might call it different.

Answer (score 0):

Honeywell makes a number of different WIFI connected tstats, if you have WIFI in your shop that would be your best bet.  I have one in a vacation home and it's awesome to be able to "turn up the heat" long before we get there.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, but... If a power outage causes the local temp to drop below 35, the tstat will go into LO mode and will NOT call for heat when power is restored. I'm using a dumb mechanical "garage" tstat to get the temp up to 40, when I then can use the smart wifi thermostat to take over... until I cut the power again and let the place freeze when I'm not using it (and not paying for heat I'm not using)

Comment: I've never heard of "LO mode" on tstat before, so I'm probably missing something.  Why on Earth would a tstat do that when the heat is most required?   I'll be very interested in responses, so once again ,   I can learn from this awesome site.